# Serving different secure sites based on port on same domain using nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, port, port-forwarding

I want to run multiple sites on the same domain, using nginx, but on different ports and want them all to use SSL

Let's say,

I have two sites `siteone.com` and `sitetwo` in the directory `/var/www/` as follows:

```
/var/www/siteone.com/
/var/www/sitetwo/
```

I want to host `siteone.com` on the domain https://siteone.com and
 `sitetwo` on the same domain but on a different port, say https://siteone.com:8080

Note: having `SSL` on both sites is important.

It might sound like I'm over engineering stuff here, but I still want to know if it is possible to do so?
I'm using `nginx` web server. What would my nginx conf file look like?

I had tried using the following but it didn't work:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name siteone.com;
  root /var/www/;

  # ssl stuff here
}

server {
  listen 8080;
  server_name sitetwo;
  root /var/www/;

  # ssl stuff here
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name siteone.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You should set the `server_name` for `site_two` also to  `siteone.com` and let nginx do the mapping based on the port. What does "it didn't work" mean? Please add error messages and log file entries to your post.

Comment: A few more details would be helpful - nginx logs for example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response @Sven . I think I figured out the problem. And I have posted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

So here are a few pointers for anyone coming here:

As pointed out correctly by @Sven in [this comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/916439/serving-different-secure-sites-based-on-port-on-same-domain-using-nginx?noredirect=1#comment1186574_916439), I should've written `siteone.com` instead of `sitetwo` in the 2nd server block in my `nginx.conf` mentioned above. But the problem doesn't end there. The site I had set up contains user login, and hence I had installed `fail2ban` on the server. Because of this, whenever I used to login to both the sites (same domain different ports) simultaneously in the same browser, `fail2ban` would block my IP. This led me to believe it was an `nginx.conf` issue which was the problem.

Why would `fail2ban` block me: Let's assume the following scenario,

I log into `siteone.com` in tab 1 of my browser. Next I open tab 2 in the same browser and log into `siteone.com:8080`. Because of this `siteone.com` login in tab 1 is invalidated. However, tab one is still trying to connect to the server in the background using incorrect authentication and because it is happening continuously `fail2ban` blocks out my IP address.

Reason why I think what I mentioned above was the issue: If I access the 2nd site in different browser or in incognito mode everything works properly.

Comment: That's an interesting issue to learn about, thanks for posting about it!